# How can I integrate custom search app's results to my iPhone's spotlight search?

Tags: iphone, spotlight, search

Is it possible to extend iOS spotlight's search results to include
data from my application? My iOS app has a separate search interface
but it would be great if there was a way to provide the results when
the user uses the phone's native search interface.

Comment: Are you the app developer, looking for a programmatic way to do this? Sounds like a question for stackoverflow.com.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different! Questions about programming, development, and listing your apps on the App Store are off topic for Ask Different. Please take a look at the [FAQs](http://apple.stackexchange.com/faq) for more info. Thanks.

Comment: Why hasn't this question been migrated to SO?